# AngularJS ng-repeat show 1 data

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Is it possible to using ng-repeat and show only 1 data.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="a in list_data">
    <h2>Nama: {{a.nama}} </h2>
    <p>Alamat: {{a.alamat}}</p>
    <p>E-mail: {{a.email}}</p>
    <p>telp: {{a.telp}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use limitTo to limit the datas of ng repeat.

try this

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="a in list_data | limitTo : 1">
            <h2>Nama: {{a.nama}} </h2>
            <p>Alamat: {{a.alamat}}</p>
            <p>E-mail: {{a.email}}</p>
            <p>telp: {{a.telp}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use ng-if condition to filter the exact data in loop :-

<div ng-if="cost == 0 && oneMessage == true">Your message </div>

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can limit your data using limitTo in ng-repeat.

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="a in list_data | limitTo: No of data you want to limit">
  <h2>Nama: {{a.nama}} </h2>
  <p>Alamat: {{a.alamat}}</p>
  <p>E-mail: {{a.email}}</p>
  <p>telp: {{a.telp}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh well you can use `limitTo`

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="a in list_data | limitTo: 1">
  <h2>Nama: {{a.nama}} </h2>
  <p>Alamat: {{a.alamat}}</p>
  <p>E-mail: {{a.email}}</p>
  <p>telp: {{a.telp}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-repeat="a in list_data | limitTo: 1">
  <h2>Nama: {{a.nama}} </h2>
  <p>Alamat: {{a.alamat}}</p>
  <p>E-mail: {{a.email}}</p>
  <p>telp: {{a.telp}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks